# How is the Solid in Oven centre Hottest

Tags: radiation, microwaves

When a solid (any material) is placed in an oven and heated, the theory of radiation works I guess. How it the centre of the solid the hottest and not the surface of the Solid which actually receives high radiation before piercing the solid.

Answer (score 1):

Microwaves work by heating up water molecules.

In general, any object is going to have the highest density of water molecules in its center because water near the surface has an easier time evaporating. Also, as time goes on, the heat in the center of the object has a harder time escaping.

Bonus tip to use this to your advantage: if you're even heating up stale cookies, sprinkle a few drops of water on them and they will get nice and gooey in the microwave.